# multi-monitor screen flashing GTX 1050

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, screen

I have a Ryzen system powered by a GTX 1050 which originally used a triple-monitor setup comprised of two HP 23" 1080p monitors and a 20" 1600x900 Samsung monitor. I used this configuration on both Windows 10 and 18.04 with no issues (using proprietary drivers).

Recently, I needed my Samsung monitor for a separate setup, and detached it from the PC in question. The setup then was comprised of the two HP monitors, one driven via HDMI, the other DP. With this setup, Windows had no issues. However, Ubuntu continually experienced randomly occurring "black screens", wherein one or both monitors would loose signal and turn completely black for less than 2 seconds with no apparent disruption to any other system functions. The displays always recover from their apparent signal loss, and any playing video or audio seem uninterrupted.

Out of curiosity, I reattached the Samsung monitor (DVI) , and the issue was no longer present. I know that is is probably not enough information to solve the problem, but I'm at a loss as to what I should do to at least diagnose what the issue actually is.

### Specs:

- Ryzen 5 2400g
- Gigabyte GTX 1050 oc
- Asus B350M-A
- HP 2311xi/Z23I, Samsung SA300

---

Update; Here is the output from xrandr with all 3 monitors attached:

> Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 5440 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
>   DVI-D-0 connected 1600x900+3840+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 443mm x 249mm
>      1600x900      60.00*+
>      1440x900      74.98    59.89
>      1280x800      74.93    59.81
>      1280x720      60.00    50.00
>      1152x864      75.00
>      1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00
>      800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25
>      720x576       50.00
>      720x480       59.94
>      640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94
>   HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
>   DP-0 connected primary 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 509mm x 286mm
>      1920x1080     60.00*+
>      1680x1050     59.95
>      1600x900      60.00
>      1440x900      59.89
>      1280x1024     60.02
>      1280x720      60.00
>      1024x768      60.00
>      800x600       60.32
>      640x480       59.94
>   DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
>   HDMI-1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 509mm x 286mm
>      1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00
>      1680x1050     59.95
>      1440x900      59.89
>      1280x1024     60.02
>      1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00
>      1024x768      60.00
>      800x600       60.32
>      720x576       50.00
>      720x480       59.94
>      640x480       59.94    59.93

---

Update_2; The random black screens do indeed occur when the Samsung monitor is attached with only one of either of the HP monitors (although seemingly much less frequently, so far I've only noticed it once or twice per uptime within minutes of each boot), however the problem does not persist when only one of the three monitors are connected individually. Also, My system is running the "Tested" 390 driver provided through the Software & Updates app:

[image: Software & Updates]

Answer (score 0):

When I look up the specs for the monitors I find that they have different refresh rates. The 2311xi is the one I'm most interested in because it runs, according to spec, at a higher refresh rate than the other two. I've personally had issues with monitors for computer builds before -- mainly those that supported high refresh rates. On those (on Windows even) I needed to install monitor profiles in order for them to work properly, black flickering, tearing and complaints like that.

Am I figuring this issue might have to do with the different refresh rates the monitors run at rather than the connector it is running over?

Could you open up a terminal and run `xrandr` and update your question? Whenever you find that one will prefer a higher refresh rate try `xrandr --screen 0 -s 1920x1080 -r 60`. Where 1920x1080 is your resolution and screen should be the target screen running higher, you can find the screen number in the initial `xrandr` as it will show per connected monitor.

You could also try the SA300 and Z23I as a pair and see if the problem still persists if that's possible, these both run at 60Hz. I wouldn't know the connectivity as I don't know what specific SyncMaster model you have.

Comment: AFAIK, all three of these monitors have always operated at 60Hz, and xrandr confirms that. Even Windows reports all 3 at 60, although I think the 2311xi and SA300 have 30Hz modes.

Comment: Hmm. Then I think it might be a connectivity/driver issue. Sanity checking here, what drivers are being used? Nvidia's are known to sometimes give users a hard time. 

There are proprietary drivers available... that is, if you want to use those to fix the problem.

Also, before attempting the install, remove any other previously installed Nvidia drivers.

Run `lshw -c video` followed with `modinfo i915` where i915 is the driver that lshw shows.

[Link to proprietary drivers](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/109244/en-us).

Comment: @johnkieran Have you got an update yet?

Comment: I've been away on business for several days, I'll update tomorrow.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, see the update in the question.